# Java - for loop output issue

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm writing a code for an assignment that needs to have this output:

```
A1  B2  C3  D4  E5  F6  G7  H8  I9  J10  K11  L12
```

This is what I have written using nested for loops ( the assignment requires use of for loops):

```
public static void outputFive()
{
    //Output 5
    for(char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'L'; alph++)
    {
        for(int x = 1; x <= 12; x++)
        {
            System.out.print(alph + x + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

And the ouput I receive is all numbers that aren't even what I want
What I get when run:

> 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
>   78 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78
>   79 80 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
>   80 81 82 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
>   81 82 83 84 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 75 76 77 78 79 80 81
>   82 83 84 85 86 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 77 78 79 80 81 82
>   83 84 85 86 87 88

Comment: Hint 1: char + int results in an int, which is why you're not seeing the characters

Comment: Hint 2: Don't need the inner loop

Comment: `System.out.print(alph);System.out.print(x+" ");`

Comment: Why the 2 loops? You say you want `A1 B2 C3 ...`, but by having 2 loops you have `A1 A2 A3 ... A12 B1 B2 B3 ...`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no place to solve assignments.

Comment: Hint 2: You only want 1 loop. You want A1 B2 C3 etc not A1 A2 ... A12 B1

Comment: Just String.valueOf(alph)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    for (char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'L'; alph++) {
        System.out.print(alph + "" + i + " ");
        i++;
    }
}
```

this will show you :

```
A1 B2 C3 D4 E5 F6 G7 H8 I9 J10 K11 L12
```

Because if you try to add a char to an int like this :

`System.out.println('A' + 1);` in fact this mean the `65 + 1` and not `A1`

Comment: what with this @AntonH ?

Comment: are you sure this work with you @AntonH i try it and it not work :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int i=1;
    for(char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'L'; alph++,i++)
    {
       System.out.print(alph);
       System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one;

```
for(int x = 1; x <= 12; x++)
{
    System.out.print(alph + "" + x + " ");
}
```

Your code shows the sum of `(int) alph + x`.

Answer (score 0):

`alph + x` evaluates to adding the ASCII character code for alph to x.

E.g. ASCII code for 'A' is 65. That's why you get 66-77 for the first loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.valueOf(alph)

```
System.out.print(String.valueOf(alph) + x + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Facts**

- you are using 2 loops

> ```
> for(char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'L'; alph++) //first loop A-L = 12x
>     for(int x = 1; x <= 12; x++) //second loop 1-12 = 12x
> ```

its means you loop your print 144 times (12x12)

- you are printing `char`

**The Problems**

- you want to print 12 times not 144
- char is considered as a numeric type

**Solution**

- remove second loop and create `int x` with start value 1
- use `String.valueOf(alph)`

> ```
> public static void outputFive()
> {
>     //Output 5
>     int x = 1;
>     for(char alph = 'A'; alph <= 'L'; alph++)
>     {
>             System.out.print(String.valueOf(alph) + x + " ");
>         x++;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the ASCII of characters

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int i = 1;
for (int alph = 65; alph <= 76; alph++)
  {
    System.out.print((char)alph + "" + i + " ");
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As will all problems, there is a requirements analysis phase.

```
System.out.print("A1  B2  C3  D4  E5  F6  G7  H8  I9  J10  K11  L12");`
```

certainly satisfies the stated functional requirements. But, there is also a non-functional requirement to use a loop because there is some sort of series in the data. There are several patterns to see in the data. In my opinion, **presuming some alphabet and performing arithmetic on characters are poor practices**. So, I take an alphabet, as in mathematics, as a given sequence:

```
// For convenience, use a String (of char) instead of an array of whatever
final String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKL"; // assumes one char per character
```

The problem then becomes outputting the elements of the sequence along with the 1-based index of the element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%c%d ", alphabet.charAt(i), (i+1)));
}
```

Comment: One reason arithmetic on characters is a poor practice is that it depends on the character encoding. Many answers refer to ASCII but that's not the encoding used by `String`, `Character` and `char`. The encoding is UTF-16, which is one of several encodings for the Unicode character set.

Comment: Unicode character set is a superset of ASCII. The numbers form 0 to 127 have the same meaning in Unicode as they have in ASCII.

Comment: @jlasierra Of course, but why mention ASCII at all, then?

Comment: Because they are working with ASCII codes. In general I would share your point of view, but i don't think that is wrong to use arithmetic on characters in this case.

Comment: @jlasierra It's a long way through the argument that UTF-16 code units are in some cases the same as ASCII. Consider [the `char` data type (and therefore the value that a `Character` object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)  and an alphabet that should give "A1 B2 C3 D4 E5 F6 G7 H8 I9 J10 K11 L12 M13 N14 O15 P16 Q17 R18 S19 T20 U21 V22 W23 X24 Y25 Z26 Æ27 Ø28 Å29".

Comment: And this alphabet "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYĲZ" that includes the letter Ĳ. (Cursor around that or select it. It's one character, and fortunately, needs only one UTF-16 code unit.)

Comment: Not only some case: ASCII characters have the same code on unicode **always**. This is not an opinion, it's a documented fact. If you are iterating just ASCII characters it's not a bad aproach to use the ASCII table. This is an opinion.

Comment: If you have other exercises to discuss there can be better solutions of course! And if you are not using ASCII alphabet in your excercice you will have to use other approaches, sure.

Answer (score -2):

public static void main(String[] args){

int i=1 ;

for (char b = 'A'; b<='Z'; b++ ){

System.out.print(a+i);
i++;

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [take care when answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) an old question which also has other answers. Code as an answer may sometimes be OK; however it's much more helpful to others if you also include an explanation with your code. Also ensure that your answer (the code) is [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). – That being said, your current code here neither compiles (variable `a` isn't defined) nor would it print out the requested result `A1  B2  C3  D4  E5  F6  G7  H8  I9  J10  K11  L12`.